# Set Value to String [] object

Tags: java

I have this string that contain month. I want to save code of the month. Example if I saved month January, it will save code of the month "1". How do I do set the value of every month.

```
String [] month= {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December"};
```

Comment: If it's array, loop the array compare the String passed and save the index+1

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for that purpose if you want to have `key-value pair structure.`

```
HashMap<Integer,String> months=new HashMap<Integer,String>(); 
months.put(1,"January"); 
// similarly put other month
```

If you would like to get value from hashmap by its key, you can use

```
String firstMonth = newMap.get(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and example. this is I need instead of String

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map instead of an array. The Map will have type `Map<String, Integer> months`. Put each of your months in the map with their corresponding value. When you need the value of each month, get it from the map by supplying the month name

Comment: thanks sir, this is what I need